# Is void guaranteed to execute action in any MonadIO?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, xmonad

I have an `IO a` value but need to pass `IO ()` to a `Xmonad` function. I use:

```
void . spawn :: MonadIO f => String -> f ()
```

What guarantees that my action will execute? Does it apply to all correct `MonadIO` instances?

Comment: `void` is simply `void x = x >> return ()`. It doesn't do anything fancy, it just makes sure a `()` value is returned after your action. It's completely unrelated to `IO` or `MonadIO`.

Answer (score 2):

That's **exactly** the purpose of `void`: to execute the action and ignore the result value. From the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:void):

> `void value` discards or ignores the result of evaluation, such as the
>   return value of an `IO` action.

Note that it says it *ignores the result of evaluation*, implying that the evaluation does take place, i.e. the side effects take place.

It can be defined as:

```
void action = action >> return ()
```

(Or in many other ways. The [`base`'s implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.html#void) is more general).

Obviously you could have a bogus definition like:

```
void _ = return ()
```

which doesn't execute the action. AFAIK the types aren't expressive enough to remove this possibility so if you really don't trust the package you'll have to write your own implementation.

Comment: ...but you absolutely should trust this package.

Comment: About the last comment: what about `void :: Functor f => f a -> f ()`? Wouldn't that force `void = fmap (const ())`? (Aside from non-terminating terms)

Comment: @chi, as long as you assume the Functor laws. Someone could write a non-law-abiding `(<$)` for a particular type that is an instance of MonadIO that executes the action 0 times, or multiple times.

Comment: "Note that it says it *ignores the result of evaluation*, implying that the evaluation does take place."  I think remark is unhelpful at best, because the term "evaluation" to my mind is unclear about what's being **forced** and what isn't.  Notably, there's no exception raised by `void (return (div 1 0)) :: IO ()`, which somebody could gloss as "`div 1 0` is not evaluated."

Comment: @LuisCasillas I clarified what I meant. If the result is ignored it means all the side effects of the monad take place, which is what the OP is interested about.